# java pop3 Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password

Tags: java, email

recently,my code connot connct mail,protel=pop3
It used to be normal，bad is recently
connect error,but username,password is right,it donot change
recently The mail client also encountered this issue
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wl9wi.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAQcP.png)

Have you met anyone recently?
I encountered a problem there：store.connect(host,995,user,passwd)

```
 public  Store getMailStore(String host, String user, String passwd, 
    boolean ifSSL, int protocol) {
        Store store=null;
        if (protocol == 1) {
            if (ifSSL) {
                Properties properties = System.getProperties();
                properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
                properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.port", "995");
                properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.port", "995");
                //        建立链接时间
                properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.connectiontimeout", "30000");
                //        读取邮件时间
                properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.timeout", "30000");
                //        发送时间时间
                properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.writetimeout", "30000");

                URLName url = new URLName("pop3", host, 995, null, user, passwd);
                Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, null);
                store = new POP3SSLStore(session, url);


                int con=0;

                do {
                    log.info("邮箱开始begin。");
                    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                    // new Date()为获取当前系统时间
                    log.info("链接邮箱时间"+df.format(new Date()));
                    try {
                        store.connect(host,995,user,passwd);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        log.info("登录邮箱失败,准备再试！");
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(10000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                        }
                    }
                    log.info("邮件链接状态：=============================="+store.isConnected());
                    if (store.isConnected()){
                        // new Date()为获取当前系统时间
                        log.info("登录邮箱成功时间"+df.format(new Date()));

                        break;
                    }
                    con++;

                } while (con<=5);
            } else {
                // 获取默认会话
                Properties prop = new Properties();
                Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(prop, null);
                log.info("准备邮箱链接实例");
                try {
                    store = session.getStore("pop3");
                    log.info("登录邮箱成功。");
                    store.connect(host, user, passwd);
                    log.info("登录邮箱成功。");
                } catch (MessagingException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }

            }
        }
//        走imap
        else  if ( protocol == 2) {
            if (ifSSL) {
                String PROTOCOL = "imap";
                Integer port = 993;
                String sslFactory = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";
                Properties props = new Properties();
                props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", PROTOCOL);
                props.setProperty("mail.imap.host", host);
                props.setProperty("mail.imap.port", "993");
                props.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");
                props.setProperty("mail.imap.starttls.enable", "true");
                props.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.class", sslFactory);


                props.setProperty("mail.imap.auth", "true");
                props.setProperty("mail.imap.auth.plain.disable", "true");
                props.setProperty("mail.imap.auth.ntlm.disable", "true");
                props.setProperty("mail.imap.auth.gssapi.disable", "true");


//                ================================================================================================
                // SSL 需要这三行
//                props.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.port", "993");
//                props.setProperty("mail.debug", "true");

                //        props.put("mail.imap.auth", true);
                //        props.put("mail.imap.auth.plain.disable", true);
                //        props.put("mail.imap.auth.ntlm.disable", true);
                //        props.put("mail.imap.auth.gssapi.disable", true);

                // SSL安全连接参数
//                props .setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

//                Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());
//                props.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
//                URLName url = new URLName("pop3", host, 995, null, user, passwd);


//            MailSSLSocketFactory sf = new MailSSLSocketFactory();
//            sf.setTrustAllHosts(true);
//            props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.socketFactory", sf);

                // 创建Session实例对象
                try {
                    Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
                    // 创建IMAP协议的Store对象
                    store = session.getStore(PROTOCOL);
                    // 连接邮件服务器
                    store.connect(user, passwd);
                    log.info("登录邮箱成功。");
                } catch (MessagingException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }

            }


        }
        return  store;

    }
```

Comment: The code should be part of the question as text (not as image) so that others can copy and adapt it to answer your question